# Vue : How to fix navbar on top inside bootstrap container class

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, containers, fixed

I have this vue app.js template :

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container shadow px-0">
      <NavBar/> 
      <Slider/> 
  </div>
</template>
```

the navbar component is inside div class with top-fixed with bootstrap :

```
<div class="fixed-top">
   <div></div>
   <nav></nav>
</div>
```

i want to display the navbar menu with container width but when I add fixed-top it will take 100% of screen like this image :

[image]

Comment: Can you try using `width:inherit` on the fixed div?

Comment: @Charlie I used {{<div class="fixed-top" style="width:inherit;">}} but still not work

Comment: Please, make a minimal reproducible example. It is pretty hard to help you withou having access to the HTML itself

Comment: @Charlie I solved it many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by add this to fixed-top div :

```
 <div class="fixed-top" style="max-width:inherit;margin:auto">
```